# How to save a 256 graylevel bitmap image to 24 bit graylevel image using matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, graphics

I have a 256 graylevel bitmap image which I created in matlab. I wanted to save this into  to 24 bit graylevel image using matlab?
here is the code that I have written in mtlab. which saves the gray level images as bmp
program to create random phase maks line pixel colums 10 columns and write
    %the file to the computer. 
    %returns the input vector Ein in 1D.

```
clear all
    close all
    for m=1:25

    mask1=zeros(1140,912);

    line=randi(255,1140,1);

    Ein(:,:,m)=line;



    % line=randi(255,540,1);
    % temp_line=line;
    % % save('line')
    % mask=zeros(1080,1)
    % i=1;
    % 
    % for k=1:length(line)
    % for i=i:i+1
    %     
    %     mask(i)=line(k);
    %     
    % end
    % i=i+1;
    % end
    % line=mask;




            mask1(:,456)=line(:,:);
    %          mask(1:1080,956)=line;
    %           mask(1:1080,957)=line;
    %            mask(1:1080,958)=line;
    %             mask(1:1080,959)=line;
    %              mask(1:1080,960)=line;
    %               mask(1:1080,961)=line;
    %                mask(1:1080,962)=line;
    %                 mask(1:1080,963)=line;
    %                  mask(1:1080,964)=line;

    %                  imwrite(unit8(mask),'Dec_21_mask_1.bmp')
    imwrite(uint8(mask1),sprintf('DMDmask_%d.bmp',m))
    %                  imwrite(uint8(mask1),'new_mask4.bmp')
    %                  f=imread('DMDmask_1.bmp');
    %                  figure
    %                  imshow(f)


    %         figure
    %  
    % imshow((mask),[])
    % Ein_angle=Fit_GrayLevel_To_Ein_Vector(mask);
    % Ein_angle=Fit_GrayLevel_To_Ein_Vector(line);
    % 
    % figure
    % 
    % imshow(Ein_angle)

    % Ein(m,:,:)=exp(1i*Ein_angle(:,:));
    % figure
    % imshow(angle(Ein));






    end
    save('Ein')
    % mask=angle(mask);
    % 
    % SLM_mask=Fit_GrayLevel_To_SLM_Vector(mask);
    % figure
    % imshow(SLM_mask)
```

Comment: 24 bits is not common for gray images, however it is common for truecolor images. Do you want 24 bits representing all those shades of gray, or do you want to save the image in truecolor format?

Comment: I want to save it as a 24 bit. I can do it by using paint or programs like that. Unfortunately I have a set of 100 images which I create in matlab. And these needs to be uploaaded on a DMD projector , unfortuantely it accepts only 24 bit  bmp. What I create in Matlab is 256 graylevel bmp.

Comment: yes I want 24 bits representing all those shades

Comment: As far as I understand, bmps 24bit is not grayscale, is truecolor, it just repeats the same 8 bit value 3 times, for RGB. It has only 2^8 grayscale values, not 2^24. That is why I was asking, as if I am not wrong, there is no standard format in bmp or png for 24 grayscale images.

Comment: I might be wrong, what I want is to upload an amplitude mask  on DMD with varying intensity level. Do you know how to do that.

Comment: I don't know Matlab because I normally use other tools, but if you want to **force** a 24-bit image, find a white pixel (`#fff`) and change it to `#ffe` which is imperceptibly close to white but actually 1/2% coloured then it has to choose to write a 24-bit colour image. Or, find a black pixel (`#000`) and set it to `#001`. Or you can do it outside Matlab with **ImageMagick** and change all your BMP files like this `mogrify -fill "#ffe" -opaque "#fff" *.bmp`

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush and had my 4-bit hat on instead of my 8-bit one in comment above. Change `#fff` to `#ffffff` and `#ffe` to `#fffffe`.

Comment: Please clean up your code before posting it here. There is no need for us to see all the commented out stuff. Please read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to save the image as a 24-bit RGB image, not a 24-bit grey-value image, as those are not at all standard and I have never seen one in my long career.

To make this into a 24-bit RGB image, you can probably do this:

```
rgb_image = repmat(mask1,[1,1,3]);
imwrite(uint8(rgb_image),sprintf('DMDmask_%d.bmp',m))
```